# How to clip what is outside scroll view when using a custom UI element?

Tags: unity, gui, scrolling, clipping

I have created a custom UI element (that use CanvasRenderer).

Here is code :

```
Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

Rect drawArea = GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;

using (VertexHelper helper = new VertexHelper())
{
    helper.AddVert(new Vector3(drawArea.xMin, drawArea.yMin), Color.white, Vector2.zero);
    helper.AddVert(new Vector3(drawArea.xMin, drawArea.yMax), Color.white, Vector2.zero);
    helper.AddVert(new Vector3(drawArea.xMax, drawArea.yMax), Color.white, Vector2.zero);
    helper.AddVert(new Vector3(drawArea.xMax, drawArea.yMin), Color.white, Vector2.zero);
    helper.AddTriangle(0, 1, 2);
    helper.AddTriangle(2, 3, 0);

    helper.FillMesh(mesh);
}

var canvas = GetComponent<CanvasRenderer>();
canvas.SetMesh(mesh);
canvas.SetMaterial(Material, null);
```

It creates a simple rectangle that is same size as rect transform.

It works great. However if I put this inside a scroll view, everything that is outside scroll area / viewport is rendered (while it should be clipped).

The scrolling works as it should (rectangle get scrolled by changing position when scrollbar is used).

I have tried to call `canvas.EnableRectClipping(...);` but without success.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question :

Custom UI component should inherit from [MaskableGraphic](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.MaskableGraphic.html) and method [OnPopulateMesh()](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.OnPopulateMesh.html) need to be overridden, like in this [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html).